# Detect if device is jailbroken or not in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, jailbreak

I have implemented the following methods to check.

```
            if(File.Exists("/Applications/Cydia.app")){
                 true;
            }

            String string = "test";
            try{
             File.WriteAllText("/private/est.txt",string);
                 true;
            }catch(Exception ex){
            }


            if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("cydia://package/com.cy.package")))
            {
                 true;
            }
```

I need to know how to call the **System, Fork, OpenSSH Service** Detection in Xamarin iOS and Suggest any other methods to check

Comment: The one who downvoted, can you say the reason or if you know the answer please share.

Answer (score 2):

ios 10 jailbreak does not use Openssh and further i would recommend to try to execute a command that needs root and if it does not return a error mark as jailbroken. Also please add jailbreak detection only if needed.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to use fork() in swift?

Comment: Hello again I am only with experience of obj c you need to find someone who knows swift